# Showing 3 mid points lie on a straight line. First year university Geomtery.

Tags: geometry

> Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be points with position vectors $a$; $b$; $c$ respectively, and let $D$ be the point such that $ABCD$ is a parallelogram.
>
> Let $U$ be the midpoint of the vector $AB$, $V$ the mid point of the vector $AC$, and $W$ the mid point of the vector $CD$.
>
> Show that $U$; $V$; $W$ lie on a straight line and find an equation for that line.

I have that the position vectors of:

$U$ is $\frac 12(a+b)$

$V$ is $\frac 12(a+c)$

$W$ is $\frac 12(c+d)$

And if $U$ $V$, $W$ are parallel then they are on a straight line, since they are multiples of each other with common factor $\frac 12$, then they are parallel.

Am I on the right track? And how would I find the equation for this line?

Comment: The position vector of $U$ should be $\frac 12 (b-a)$, and similarly for the other vectors, $V$ and $W$

Comment: How would I show that these are all on a straight line?

Comment: They _can't_ be all on one line. Draw some examples to see.

Comment: Well the question asks to show that they lie on a straight line?

Comment: Express $d$ with respect to $a$, $b$ and $c$. If $U$, $V$ and $W$ are aligned, then the vectors $V-U$ and $W-U$ are collinear. Show the collinearity. Then it's just the classic equation of line through a point with a given direction vector.

Comment: @lioness99a No, the OP has it right. $U$, $V$ and $W$ are the midpoints of the corresponding line segments, otherwise the assertion is not true in general.

Comment: @amd The line segment between $A$ and $B$ is equal to $b-a$, therefore the halfway point along it ($U$) is equal to $\frac 12(b-a)$

Comment: @lioness99a No, the *line segment* between $A$ and $B$ is $(1-t)a+tb$, and its midpoint is $(a+b)/2$, i.e., $a+(b-a)/2$. You’re describing a point that’s at the same distance from the *origin* as half of the distance between $A$ and $B$. The wording of the problem is unfortunate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $d$? If $ABCD$ is a parallelogram, you have $d=a-b+c$ (why?). Thus 
$$W=\tfrac12(a-b+2c)\;.$$

If you draw a diagram, you will notice that the line through these points has the same direction as $AD$ and $BC$. So a parametric form of your line might be

$$P(\lambda)=\tfrac12(a+b)+\lambda(c-b)\;.$$

Then for $\lambda=0$ you get $U$, for $\lambda=\tfrac12$ you get $V$ and for $\lambda=1$ you get $W$.